# jQuery will not set a higher scoped object in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have a jQuery callback function. In that function I want it to change the value of a variable that is in a higher scope, but for some reason it is not doing that. Here is the code:

```
function add() {
    var returnedData = {
        my_id: 0
    };

    $.post("add_event.php", { event : toSendText }, function(data) {
        returnedData.my_id = 5;
    }, "json");

    if(add_page == true){
        alert(returnedData.my_id);
        window.open('content-list.php?cal_id=');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is asynchronous, so that `returnedData.my_id = 5;` happens **after** your `alert()` does (the data comes back from the server at some point later, when the request finishes).

To make this work like you want, you need to continue working in the callback once your data is available, like this:

```
function add() {
  $.post("add_event.php", { event : toSendText }, function(data) {
     if(data.add_page == true) {
       //use data in some way here presumably
       window.open('content-list.php?cal_id=' + data.id); //maybe this?
     }
  }, "json");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax( settings )
```

> **async** *Boolean*
>   **Default**: true
>
> By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronous (i.e. this is set to true
>   by default). If you need synchronous
>   requests, set this option to false.
>   Cross-domain requests and dataType:
>   "jsonp" requests do not support
>   synchronous operation. Note that
>   synchronous requests may temporarily
>   lock the browser, disabling any
>   actions while the request is active.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The `jQuery.post( settings )` by default doesn't pass the parameter `async` so it assumes `true`

> This is a shorthand Ajax function,
>   which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/